# Read with subsampling in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, memory, scanf, formatted-input

Is there anyway to read with subsampling in MATLAB? The input data look like:

`id=3,age=25, 0.5 0.5 0.2 0.6 0.6 0.5`

`id=1,age=15, 0.5 0.8 0.2 0.9 0.6 0.9`

`id=7,age=24, 0.5 0.2 0.9 0.6 0.1 0.5`

(Edited) For the LAST SIX columns, I only want columns that are multiple of three (i.e. the 3rd column and the 6th column in the LAST SIX COLUMNS, which is equivalent to the 5th column and the 8th column in the whole data file) be read. That is, a matrix like:

`0.2 0.5`

`0.2 0.9`

`0.9 0.5`

Ideally, the code looks like:

```
for line=1:maxLine
  header(line,:) = fscanf(fid,'id=%d,age=%d,',[1,2]);
  content(line,:) = fscanf(fid,'only read columns multiple of three');
end;
```

I know that I can read the whole line and sub-sample, the problem is, the array I'm dealing with has large scale, 10k+ columns, I do not want to consume too much memory.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple of three"? `0.2` and `0.5` aren't divisible by 3 and the only number that appears 3 times in any row or column is `0.5`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the way:
if you use `fopen` you can get access to file only one time, so you can't do it in a loop. So you need to load all necessary data in one array and then transpose it. 
Your desire to save free memory is achieved by ignoring some elements:

```
 fid = fopen('new.txt','r');
 A = fscanf(fid, 'id=%d,age=%d, %*f %*f %f %*f %*f %f\n', [4 inf])
```

I used your data and get this result:

```
A =

    3.0000    1.0000    7.0000
   25.0000   15.0000   24.0000
    0.2000    0.2000    0.9000
    0.5000    0.9000    0.5000
```

as you can read here http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html?searchHighlight=fscanf `fscanf` reads data into columns, that is why we need to transpose it.
So using `A=A'` gives result you want:

```
A =

    3.0000   25.0000    0.2000    0.5000
    1.0000   15.0000    0.2000    0.9000
    7.0000   24.0000    0.9000    0.5000
```

Now you can make two different matrices if needed.

Comment: I believe I can use for-loop in the fashion `for i=1:DataLine \n A(i,:) = fopen(fid,'format',[1 6]); \n end;`

Comment: I didn't try this version. But you can't use `fopen` for reading data. Looks like you made mistake and mean `fscanf`. Is it? if so, I tried some loops versions and already wrote to you - I faced the problem - `fopen` correctly works only once. If I used it in a loop I had to use `fopen` every iteration but then it read from the start of the file.

If you can solve this let me know!

Comment: That's a typo. I mean `fopen` out side the loop, and `fscanf` inside the loop. Thanks for showing the use of `%*f`. I never know that. The problem is, we have 10k+ columns, and we can not write `%*f` for thousands of times. We need to use iteration to handle elements reading.

Comment: Look, in my example I used `fscanf` once but it read all txt file. So, if you have 10k+ strings of same structure (every string has this `'id ... ages'` and the same number of digits) it will works. `fscanf` reads file while it's data looks like a second argument of `fscanf`.